# Setting size of text in datagrid wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How I can set the size of the text in the datagrid from the xaml .
what property is doing it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TextElement.FontSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textelement.fontsize.aspx) for example.